How to implement a message system with Django across domain and subdomains?
I want to develop a web application using Django. This application is a support network. End users will create support tickets via the 'www.mydomain.com' web address, and employees will respond to these tickets via an admin panel at 'support.mydomain.com'. Tickets will be single-threaded, meaning, for example, that end users cannot write another message until the support team responds. I'll use cPanel for hosting.
How can I establish the connection between the domain and subdomain in this application? Should I develop two separate projects and connect them with REST Framework, or is there a better way?

You can use two apps serving their own purpose, in a single project. And communicate through APIs
